# Constant time complexity with assignment

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am totally confused with my script of my lecture in time complexity analysis and I need some help. Here is the provided example of the lecture and I didn't find any useful answer.

```
monthly_installment = 50.00;
i = 1;
interest = 0.005;
assets = 100.00;

while i<n 
{
    assets = monthly_installment + assets + assets * interest;
    i = i + 1; 
}
```

For this example we have:
4 assignments outside from while,
(n + 1) comparisons inside the while loop,
n*(2 adds + 1 assignment + 1 mul),
n*(1 add + 1 assignment). So assuming all together f(n) = 4 + 7n + 1, which belongs to O(n).

While in the exercise:

```
sum = 0;
i = n;
while i > 0 
{
   sum = sum + 1;
   i = floor(i/2);
}
```

In this case the solution is the order of log(n), O(log(n)). Why in this case isn't in sum assignment n*(1 assignment + 1 add) = 2n the order of O(n)? What's the difference here? Is in any case every assignment time complexity i.e. a = b + c constant O(1)?

Comment: C or C++? Which one is relevant here?

Comment: If you're ever stumped on these, try graphing the run-time vs. varying values of *n* and see which type of curve best fits the results. The difference between *n* and *log n* is pretty subtle for small values, but dramatic for larger ones.

Comment: The difference is that in the first example `i` is increased by 1, whereas in the second example `i` is divided by 2. So if `n` is 8, then in the first example, the values of `i` are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, but in the second example the values of `i` are 8,4,2,1. To make the difference even more obvious, consider `n = 65536` and list the values of `i` for both cases.

Comment: To put it another way, when analyzing a loop, the first thing to do is determine how many times the loop executes. Then multiply that by the complexity of the body of the loop. In the second example, the statements in the body of the loop are both O(1), so the body has complexity O(1). The loop itself repeats O(log(n)) times. So the complexity is O(log(n)) * O(1) which is O(log(n)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was asking also about ```sum = sum + 1;```. Should we do consider as O(n) or O(1) and why? Sum will give as back sum = 1,2,3,4 which means n times.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1, i will be 1, 2, 3, ..., n and computed n times.
In case 2, i will be floor(n / 2), floor(floor(n / 2) / 2), ..., 1, which decrease more quickly. Not all integers will be computed here.